# Dispel Magic vs Magic Resistance

Tags: dnd-5e, spells

One of my PCs cast Dispel Magic (3rd level slot) on NPC Wizard with a magic resistance. Must he roll spellcasting ability check against NPC's 9th level spell with disadvantage?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Magic Resistance gives **advantage on saving throws against spells and other magical effects** - it does not impose disadvantage against others.

In your case, the PC is casting Dispel Magic and would roll their ability check as normal.

However, that's still a DC19 ability check against their spellcasting - which is no easy feat. Most classes do not get proficiency added to this (only their spellcasting ability modifier). A Bard with Jack-of-all-trades is an exception.